# Impossible to use my class in an Azure function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have a problem with my Python function app.

I admit I don't try a lot of things but I just don't understand why it's not working.
Both the class and the function exist in 'Script1.py'.

In [this Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators#unit-testing), it's said I need to use absolute import and create a '''**init**.py''' file. I tried to import like this :

```
from shared.Script1 import class1
```

and like this :

```
from shared import Script1
```

Both of them do not work. And if I don't import my files in a try/except block, I get the worst message 'No HTTP triggers found'.

**My project** :

```
|- function_app.py
|- host.json
|- local.settings.json
|- requirements.txt
|- shared
||- __init__.py
||- Script1.py
||- Script2.py
```

**function_app.py** :

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging
try:
    from shared.Script1 import class1
except ImportError as e:
    logging.error(f"Erreur d'importation : {e}")

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.function_name(name="httpTrigger1")
@app.route(route="route")
def route(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    caller = req.params.get('caller')
    accessPath = req.params.get('accessPath')
    code, response = class1.function1(accessPath, caller)
    return func.HttpResponse(body=response, status_code=code)
```

**Logs Azure function** :

```
Result: Failure Exception: NameError: name 'class1' is not defined
```

Comment: make sure you define `class` as  like: `class YourClassName `. and used it proper name.

Comment: @Tanveer I rightly declared my class in my script1 : 'class class1:'. The method I tried to import is a staticmethod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem and it was not what I expected. One parameter from 'host.json' needed to be changed.

Initial 'host.json' version :

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Thanks to @Ikhtesam, I tried to create a new functions app and I discovered the difference with a brand new 'host.json' file with a different construction :

New 'host.json' version :

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the below folder structure and following codes in the respective files.

[image]

***function_app.py***-

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging
try:
    from shared.script1 import class1
except ImportError as e:
    logging.error(f"Error : {e}")

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    caller = req.params.get('caller')
    accessPath = req.params.get('accessPath')
    response = class1.function1(accessPath, caller)
    return func.HttpResponse(body=response)
```

**`script1.py`**-

```py
class class1:
    @staticmethod
    def function1(access_path, caller):
        # Implement your logic here
        if access_path == "12" and caller == "13":
            return "Access granted for caller1 to path1"
        else:
            return "Access denied"
```

Then I executed my function by clicking **fn + f5** or **func host start** and got the expected response.

[image]

[image]